# sql multiple count result wrong on view

Tags: php, mysql

mytable :

```
id   name    value      prob
```

```
1    andy    100         0
2    luna    0           1
3    joe     0           0
4    linda   50          3
5    rob     25          2
6    steph   100         0
7    rudy    0           0
```

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('mydb') or die (mysql_error());
     $sql   = "SELECT Count(*) AS total, 
                      (SELECT Count(*) FROM mytable WHERE mytable.value=100) AS filled, 
                      (SELECT Count(*) FROM mytable WHERE mytable.prob>=1) AS problems 
               FROM mytable";

     $query = mysql_query( $sql )  or die(mysql_error());
              while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ){
              $totals=$rows['total'];
              $fills=$rows['filled'];
              $probs=$rows['problems'];
 ?>
             TOTAL <?php echo $totals; ?>
             CLEARED <?php echo $fills; ?>
             PROBLEMS <?php echo $probs; ?>     
<?php } ?>
```

im generating query with navicat.. and the result was correct but when write code at my view get :

```
TOTAL 7
CLEARED 0
PROBLEMS 0
```

need results like this :

```
TOTAL 7
CLEARED 2
PROBLEMS 3
```

Comment: On what basis you clear the problem? Any value for it?

Comment: Try to use alias in subquery... ex: (SELECT Count(*) FROM mytable mt1 WHERE mt1.value=100)

Comment: If u want count than no need to use sub queries u can get by using php. Also note that mysql_* are deprecated and close in Php 7

Comment: @Baro im trying use it.. its result was correct on navicat.. same with my query above.. but confused when echoing result i get problem on my view

Comment: @devpro need count multiple columns rows but other with some condition..